# Struggling with a lineplot (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I have the following (sample) data:

```
testdata <- data.frame(theft=sample(size=100, c("yes", "no"), replace=T),
                   assault=sample(size=100, c("yes", "no"), replace=T),
                   robbery=sample(size=100, c("yes", "no"), replace=T),
                   agegrp=sample(size=100, c("10-20", "21-40", ">40"), replace=T))

theft <- table(testdata$theft, testdata$agegrp)[2,]
assault <- table(testdata$assault, testdata$agegrp)[2,]
robbery <- table(testdata$robbery, testdata$agegrp)[2,]

table <- rbind(theft, assault, robbery)
```

My goal is to create a line-plot (with ggplot) showing three different lines (for each offence type) over the age groups. Do I first have to re-arrange them into something like this?

```
offence  agegrp   count
/--------/--------/---------
theft    >40      22
theft    10-20    11
theft    21-40    22
...      ...      ...
```

How can I do this (not manually)? And how would I plot it then?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=agegrp, y=count, color=offence) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create `table` dataset if you manage to reshape your original dataset and then plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

testdata %>%
  group_by(agegrp) %>%                # for each age group
  summarise_all(~sum(.=="yes")) %>%   # count "yes" in all columns
  gather(offence,count,-agegrp) %>%   # reshape data
  mutate(agegrp = factor(agegrp, levels = c("10-20","21-40",">40"))) %>%  # specify order of levels (useful for plotting)
  ggplot(aes(x=agegrp, y=count, color=offence, group=offence)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I get this error message when executing your code: Error in UseMethod("as.fun_list") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.fun_list' applied to an object of class "formula"

Comment: Which line produces that error? Can you run it step by step and check?

Comment: The line with summarise_all.

Comment: Can't replicate the error. Can you refresh R, update the package version and check again?

Comment: Now, I've tried it on another computer and it worked! Thank you! I have just another question: How can I plot the **percentages** of the "yes" values for each group instead of the absolute values?

Comment: You have to calculate that before you plot. Try '~sum(.=="yes")/length (.)'